# Can Beskar Rust?

Tags: star-wars, the-mandalorian

In *The Mandalorian* Chapter 10: "The Passenger," Peli Motto tells Din Djarin,

> Quit your cryin' you'll rust.

While it would be entirely in character for that to simply be a joke, do we have any evidence that beskar can rust?

Comment: 'Beskar Rust' sounds like an awesome D&D character name

Comment: I haven't found anything for or against rust so far, but at least Tales of the Jedi-era Mandalorians didn't seem worried about rain: http://static1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20081205060056/starwars/images/6/61/Mandalore.jpg

Comment: That would be somewhat surprising if stuff highly resistant to lightsaber would be vulnerable to saltwater... and ironically hilarious ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like a lot of Mandalorian lore, this has been retconned. The most we know about long-lived Beskar that has been neglected would be from [Boba Fett's armor](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Boba_Fett%27s_armor). We first see it (post-sarlacc) in *The Mandalorian* in Chapter 9, where Cobb Vanth is wearing it as-is

[image: Cobb Vanth in Beskar]

While the paint job hasn't held up all that well, there's not really any visible rust. Fett later regains the armor and repaints it, so we don't know if there was any rust we couldn't see.

Beyond that, the Empire smelted most of the Beskar into ingots, which would have removed anything like rust. Din Djarin's full Beskar set is fairly new in canon, and presumably Bo-katan's group from Mandalore are maintaining their armor.

The answer (so far) is: **there are no known instances of it rusting, even if neglected**

Comment: Tatooine isn't exactly brimming with moisture though

Comment: @Valorum Maybe not, but that sarlacc had to have had some in its gut. And [things can still rust in the desert](https://www.quora.com/Do-things-rust-in-the-desert)

Comment: Tatooine is drier than the priest desert on Earth. But sure.

Comment: @Valorum *puts on tin foil hat* THATS BECAUSE THEY ARE FARMING ALL THE MOISTURE!